# Insert main table's primary key into child table multiple times

Tags: c++, ms-access-2007, ado, sql-insert

I have `MS Access 2007` database with the following schema:

Main table `Object< # Object_PK, ... >`

Child table `Electric_Consumption< $ Object_PK, # Electric_Consumption_PK, ... >`

Child table `Water_Consumption< $ Object_PK, # Water_Consumption_PK, ... >`

Child table `Educational_Object< $ Object_PK, # Educational_Object_PK, ... >` which has child tables defined like this:

`School< $ Educational_Object_PK, # School_PK, ... >`

`University< $ Educational_Object_PK, # University_PK, ... >`

Here is the picture that should make things clearer:

[image]

I use `ADO` and `C++` to insert data.

First I need to enter data for main table `Object`. I can successfully do that with `INSERT` query.

My problem is following:

After the above operation I need to insert `Object`'s **primary key** into child tables, since it is their foreign key.

Allow me to describe exactly what I need so community can help me:

As I said, first I insert data into main table `Object`.

Then I need to insert data **and `Object`'s primary key** into child tables.

Browsing through Internet I have found `@@IDENTITY` that might help me but I do not know if it works for my case.

To make things harder, this will be done in `for loop` ( the value of the `Object_PK` is the same in every `INSERT` and is equal to the value of **the last inserted record** for the `Object` ) , something like this:

```
for ( //... ) 
   L"INSERT INTO Electric_Consumption ( Object_PK, field1, field2 ... ) 
       values ( Object_pk // should I use here @@IDENTITY ? );
```

Then the same thing should be repeated for tables `Water_Consumption` and `Educational_Object`.

After I finish this, I need to add data in the `Educational_Object`'s child tables.

The same as above, only instead of `Object_PK` I need to add `Educational_Object_PK`.

Here is the pseudo-code to clarify things better:

```
L"INSERT INTO Object ( ... ) values ( ... ); //this is OK

for ( ... )
    L" INSERT INTO Electric_Consumption ( Object_PK, ... ) 
        values ( Object_PK, ... )"; // should I use @@IDENTITY here
                                    // to get Object_PK ??
for ( ... )
    L" INSERT INTO Water_Consumption ( Object_PK, ... ) 
        values ( Object_PK, ... )"; // should I use @@IDENTITY here
                                    // to get Object_PK ??
for ( ... )
    L" INSERT INTO Educational_Object ( Object_PK, ... ) 
        values ( Object_PK, ... )"; //  should I use @@IDENTITY here
                                    // to get Object_PK ??
for ( ... )
    L" INSERT INTO School ( Educational_Object_PK, ... ) 
        values ( Educational_Object_PK, ... )";// should I use @@IDENTITY here
                                    // to get Educational_Object_PK ??
for ( ... )
    L" INSERT INTO University ( Educational_Object_PK, ... ) 
        values ( Educational_Object_PK, ... )";// should I use @@IDENTITY here
                                    // to get Educational_Object_PK ??
```

Can you please tell me which `SQL statement` to use for this, and demonstrate how to use it by providing a small pseudo code?

I understand that my description of the problem might be confusing so if you need further clarification leave a comment and I will edit my post.

Thank you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` as a multiuser-safe way to retrieve the most recently-created AutoNumber (sometimes called "IDENTITY") value. The things to remember are:

- You execute a `SELECT @@IDENTITY` query immediately after you perform the INSERT on the parent table.
- You store the returned value in a `Long Integer` variable.
- You use the variable to populate the Foreign Key values in the child table(s).

The following is VBA code, but you can treat it as pseudo-code:

```vbs
Dim lngObject_PK As Long, lngEducational_Object_PK As Long

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Object] ([Description]) VALUES (?)"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "my new Object")
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT @@IDENTITY", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
lngObject_PK = rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Debug.Print "Object_PK of newly-created Object record: " & lngObject_PK

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Electric_Consumption] ([Object_PK],[Description]) VALUES (?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngObject_PK)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "my new Electric_Consumption")
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Educational_Object] ([Object_PK],[Description]) VALUES (?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngObject_PK)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "my new Educational_Object")
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT @@IDENTITY", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
lngEducational_Object_PK = rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Debug.Print "Educational_Object_PK of newly-created Educational_Object record: " & lngEducational_Object_PK

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [School] ([Educational_Object_PK],[Description]) VALUES (?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput, , lngEducational_Object_PK)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, "my new School")
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just one question: Maybe a better choice is to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or `IDENTITY_CURRENT()`? Are they available in `MS Access`? Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff As far as I know `SELECT @@IDENTITY` is the only such option available for Access databases. The other two you mentioned are for T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server).

Comment: Just one more question: In order to maintain [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) model, should I use `transactions`? If that is the case can you modify your answer with small code example that illustrates this? I have placed my `ADO` calls in `try/catch` block. I have already upvoted your answer. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff If you want to wrap your operations in a transaction then simply invoke the `BeginTrans` method on the ADODB.Connection object before you start INSERTing, then use the `CommitTrans` method to complete the transaction or use the `RollbackTrans` method in your `catch` block if something goes wrong. As for whether you *need* to use a transaction in this case, that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Well, if I insert 2 out of 5 parameters successfully, and error happens on third one, an exception is thrown. If I do not do `rollback` then the object will remain inserted, with the previous two parameters, which is a "dirty writing" in my opinion. That is why I thought that if I use `rollback` I could undo the **whole** insert, **leaving database in consistent state**. I think you "get the picture" of what I am trying to say. I am really interested in your point of view. Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If the Object_PK is predictable, such as you are using an Autonumber field, you could first determine the next key by something like:
    SELECT Max([Object_ID]+1) AS NewKey
FROM ObjectTable;
then use that for all of the other tables (or simply retrieve the MAX key value after storing the Object);  How is the primary key defined?

Comment: All the primary keys are `AUTONUMBER`values. I already use `SELECT MAX( Object_PK ) ...` but this has a flaw: Right now everything works with single user, but if multiple users use my application then the query you suggest will execute multiple times which may result in wrong primary key being returned. That is why I have asked the question. Thank you for your help. Best regards.

Comment: In a multiuser environment, you have two choices. You can use a function similar to the following that you can call; passing it the value to store in the new Object record, and receiving the key value in return.
Function Add_Object(strObjectName As String) As Long
Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ObjectTable")
rs.AddNew
rs!object_Title = strObjectName
Add_Object = rs!Object_ID
rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
Add error trap to above and you should be OK.  Otherwise, you could create a TRANSACTION.

Comment: I do not know Visual Basic, but I will try to convert your code into C++ with the help of the internet. I have never used transactions either, so it will take me time to implement your solution. We shall stay in touch, please be patient. Thank you for your help. Best regards.